# Hide value when hide element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make a select box . The value of select box and input text will show below `<hr>` tag like

[image]

Input text only show when value in select box is `Two`. But when i switch to other value in select box to make input display none. But value not disappear. I try to make that value disappear when input is hidden. How to do that thank.

Here is my

```js
function Controller ($scope) {
    $scope.myDropDown = 'one';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="one" selected>One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="test" ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
    <hr>    
    {{myDropDown}} {{test}}
</div>
```

Comment: you can surround the text with <span></span> and make it hidden when the model equal something with ng-show, but i'm not sure what you want to hide / show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your code :

```js
function Controller ($scope) {
    $scope.myDropDown = 'one';
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
        <select ng-model="myDropDown">
              <option value="one" selected>One</option>
              <option value="two">Two</option>
              <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input ng-model="test" ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
        <hr>    
        {{myDropDown}} <span ng-show="myDropDown=='two'">{{test}}</span> 
    </div>
```

And here is another solution that I like more :

```js
function Controller ($scope) {
  $scope.myDropDown = 'one';
  $scope.showMe = false;
  $scope.changevalue = function(a){
    if(a == 'two'){
      $scope.showMe = true;
    }
    else{
      $scope.showMe = false;
      $scope.test = null;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
  <select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-change="changevalue(myDropDown)">
    <option value="one" selected>One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input ng-model="test" ng-show="showMe" type="text">
  <hr>    
  {{myDropDown}} {{test}}
</div>
```